# How to convert string of binary values back to char

Tags: c++, arrays, string, binary, bitset

Example

NOTE: that i am only concerned about letters. so bitset 000001 would be `a` or `A`.

I have a `string` named `s` with the value `"abc"`.
I take each `char` of the `string` and convert it to binary value through
the use of `bitset`.

e.g

```
bitset <6> b1 = s[0];   //a
bitset <6> b2 = s[1];   //b
bitset <6> b3 = s[2];   //c
```

then i want to put the results into an `array` of `strings`. The name of the array is `arr` (and each `string` of the `array` will represent the binary value of each `char`)

e.g

```
arr[0]   //will hold the value of char 'a' in binary form which is 000001
arr[1]   //will hold the value of char 'b' in binary form which is 000010
arr[2]   //will hold the value of char 'c' in binary form which is 000011
```

and the way i convert each `char` from the `string` to binary is

```
arr[0] = b1.to_string();    //arr[0] is now 000001
arr[1] = b2.to_string();    //arr[1] is now 000010
arr[2] = b3.to_string();    //arr[2] is now 000011
```

**Now here lies my problem.
How do i convert them back to `char`?**

e.g.

```
//I want each char to take back the each corresponding letter from the binary values

char c1;   //How do i make the arr[0] value of 000001 to become 'a' again?
char c2;   //Same here
char c3;   //And here
```

Comment: A common question, sure you could not find it?

Comment: If you already have a string representation of the binary value and want to go back to `char`, why not just remove the `bitset` middleman and do something like `static_cast<char>(std::stoi(arr[i]) + 64)` ? Then again, I don't know if you need the `bitset` for further operations later in your code

Comment: Thanks. No i don't need it for anything further. Would that work then without bitset like you said ( i cant try it t this time but i will try it later when i get home).

Comment: Just tested , it is working, but I forgot something on my previous comment which I can no longer edit. [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae972e7c3985608b) is a live demo.

Comment: thanks @  Alejandro. Can you explain the 0,2 part in the code? Thanks again :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want to start at ASCII code 64, and that `'a'` (or `'A'`) is simply `000001` in that case, then you can simply do

```
c1 = static_cast<char>(std::bitset<6>(arr[0]).to_ulong() + 64); //
```

`'A'` in decimal is `65`, in binary is `0b01000001`. `'a'` in decimal is `97`, in binary is `0b01100001`. In your code, you use a `bitset<6>` to store `'a'` (or `'A'`). A `bitset<6>` can only represent `2^6` symbols, i.e. `64`, so you will encounter cutting. Basically the `2` most significant bits will be cut. In this case, `bitset<6>('A')` becomes `0b000001`, i.e. `1` in decimal, and `bitset<6>('a')` becomes `0b1000001`, i.e. `33` in decimal. You can now convince yourself that adding back `64` produces the right result.

**EDIT**

Note that you can also use [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) (C++11 only) to convert the bit string from base 2 to decimal, as mentioned in the other answers:

```
char c1 = static_cast<char>(std::stoi(arr[0], nullptr, 2) + 64);
```

Comment: Thanks mate can you explain a bit your code and then i will choose it best answer.

Comment: @George added, see if it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks @vsoftco can you explain the last line a bit more?

Comment: @George the one with adding 64 (XOR) was a bit unnecessary, I deleted it. What I wanted to say is that `64` in binary is `0b01000000`, and adding it to the 6-bit representation of `a` or `A` produces the right result. Although it's easier to do it in decimal, as I did in the main answer.

Comment: Why don't you use a `std::bitset<8>` instead? In that case, it will have the same amount of bits as a `char`, so you won't have any truncation, and you won't need all this mumbo-jumbo with adding stuff like `64`. In fact, even 7 bits are enough to represent all ASCII characters.

Comment: Up-voted Also my reason of using 6 bits is that i want to have a being 000001 etc not 0b01100001 (since i am only using letters) For an encryption algorithm. It would be cumbersome to ask for the user to input his 0b01100001 instead 000001 basically :P

Answer (score 1):

consider the following:

```
 std::cout << "abc" << std::endl;

 std::cout << 'a' << 'b' << 'c' << std::endl;

 std::cout << std::dec
           << static_cast<int>('a') << " "
           << static_cast<int>('b') << " "
           << static_cast<int>('c')  << " "<< std::endl;

 std::cout << std::hex
           << static_cast<int>('a') << " "
           << static_cast<int>('b') << " "
           << static_cast<int>('c')  << " "<< std::endl;
```

with output

abc

abc

97 98 99

61 62 63

This shows that each char *is* binary, and 97 dec *is* 0x61 hex.

Conversion (to / from binary via bitset) is not necessary.

(or perhaps I am not understanding why you want to do nothing 
in a somewhat complicated fashion).

Note that static_cast<> causes no code gen.
Note that std::dec and std::hex do no change to the data, just to the radix.

edit ---
For only 8 bits, you might consider this ... no endian issues.

```
 std::cout << ((('a' >> 7) & 1) ? '1' : '0')
           << ((('a' >> 6) & 1) ? '1' : '0')
           << ((('a' >> 5) & 1) ? '1' : '0')
           << ((('a' >> 4) & 1) ? '1' : '0')
           << ((('a' >> 3) & 1) ? '1' : '0')
           << ((('a' >> 2) & 1) ? '1' : '0')
           << ((('a' >> 1) & 1) ? '1' : '0')
           << ((('a' >> 0) & 1) ? '1' : '0') << "  "
           << ((('b' >> 7) & 1) ? '1' : '0')
           << ((('b' >> 6) & 1) ? '1' : '0')
           << ((('b' >> 5) & 1) ? '1' : '0')
           << ((('b' >> 4) & 1) ? '1' : '0')
           << ((('b' >> 3) & 1) ? '1' : '0')
           << ((('b' >> 2) & 1) ? '1' : '0')
           << ((('b' >> 1) & 1) ? '1' : '0')
           << ((('b' >> 0) & 1) ? '1' : '0') << "  "
           << ((('c' >> 7) & 1) ? '1' : '0')
           << ((('c' >> 6) & 1) ? '1' : '0')
           << ((('c' >> 5) & 1) ? '1' : '0')
           << ((('c' >> 4) & 1) ? '1' : '0')
           << ((('c' >> 3) & 1) ? '1' : '0')
           << ((('c' >> 2) & 1) ? '1' : '0')
           << ((('c' >> 1) & 1) ? '1' : '0')
           << ((('c' >> 0) & 1) ? '1' : '0') << "  "
           << std::endl;


 std::cout << std::dec << std::endl;


 // with variable
 char zulu = 'A';

 std::cout << std::dec
           << "NOTE: in this cout, every use of zulu is a 'read' \n"
           << "   zulu: " << zulu                               << "  \n"

           << "   dec : " << std::dec << static_cast<int>(zulu) << "  \n"
           << "   --- : " << zulu                               << "  \n" // zulu not changed

           << "   hex : " << std::hex << static_cast<int>(zulu) << "  \n"
           << "   --- : " << zulu                               << "  \n" // zulu not changed

           << "   bin : "
           << (((zulu >> 7) & 1) ? '1' : '0')
           << (((zulu >> 6) & 1) ? '1' : '0')
           << (((zulu >> 5) & 1) ? '1' : '0')
           << (((zulu >> 4) & 1) ? '1' : '0')
           << (((zulu >> 3) & 1) ? '1' : '0')
           << (((zulu >> 2) & 1) ? '1' : '0')
           << (((zulu >> 1) & 1) ? '1' : '0')
           << (((zulu >> 0) & 1) ? '1' : '0')    << "  \n"
           << "   --- : " << zulu                               << "  \n" // zulu not changed

           << " bitset: " << std::bitset<8>(zulu)               << "  \n"
           << "   zulu: " << zulu                               << "  \n\nzulu not changed!" // zulu not changed

           << std::endl;
```

Comment: I need the binary values for some outputs i need to show. I am bit lost with your example :P i will try to understand it better when i get home. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you stated you no longer need the `std::bitset` after you convert from binary back to your `char` representation, you can avoid using it for the conversion.

```
static_cast<char>(std::stoi(arr[i],0,2) + 64);
```

Interprets the original binary representation as a base 2 (binary) number and adds 64. Since you have the original `char`s stored in a binary format in the `arr` array, you can pass them to `std::stoi` and specify that the values are base 2, in the 3rd parameter. `std::stoi` requires 3 parameters: the string you're trying to convert, a pointer to an int that will store the index of the first unconverted character (unneeded here,so can be left as `0`), and the base of the string argument. [Here's more info on that](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).  The result of the `std::stoi` call is the base 10 (decimal) equivalent of the binary values.  vsoftco's answer explains why adding 64 is the appropriate operation to do here after getting a decimal representation.  The result of this is given back as a `char`.

If you can afford to use a larger `std::bitset` you can even scrap adding 64.

Here's a live demo:

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae972e7c3985608b)

Comment: Can you explain this part? `(arr[i],0,2)` Also thanks for the code :)