# convert bitset<64> to string every 8 bit

Tags: c++, string, loops, bit-manipulation, bitset

I want to convert a `std::bitset<64>` to a `std::string`.

Here's what I have tried：

```
std::string bitsetToChar(std::bitset<64> bitset){
  std::bitset<8> bit;

  for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
      bit[j] = bitset[i*8+j];
    }
    // new char c using above bits
    // link chars
  }
}
```

The result should be a string consisting of 8 chars.

### Edit

Here's an example with 16 bits:

```
 bitset<16> bits = 0100000101000010;
 // first 8 bit is 01000001, second is 01000010
```

Output should be a `std::string` with content `AB`.

Comment: Do you want interleaved bits or do you want the first 8 bits, then the next 8 bits and so on until you have 8, 8bit stings?

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages. The code you are showing is C++.

Comment: I want 8 chars and a char is 8 bit

Comment: Sorry for my mistake.@crashmstr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pretty portable solution:

```
template<size_t N>
std::string bitset_to_string(std::bitset<N> bits){
    static_assert(N % CHAR_BIT == 0, L"bitset size must be multiple of char");
    std::string toReturn;
    for(size_t j = 0; j < N/CHAR_BIT; ++j)
    {
        char next = 0;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < CHAR_BIT; ++i)
        {
            size_t index = N - (CHAR_BIT*j) - i - 1;
            size_t pos = CHAR_BIT - i - 1;
            if (bits[index])
                next |= (1 << pos); 
        }
        toReturn.push_back(next);
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

### [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e509e65705d2c582)

It uses [`CHAR_BIT`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/) as defined by climits.h to get the number of bits in a byte (and a `char` is guaranteed to be 1 byte).

The gist is that we process the bitset 1 byte at a time from left to right.

Two tests:

```
std::bitset<16> bits{"0100000101000010"}; // AB
std::bitset<8> bits2{"01000001"};
std::cout << bitset_to_string(bits) << std::endl;
std::cout << bitset_to_string(bits2) << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
AB
A
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that I understood your problem. Since your question looks like homework, here's an example that might help you, not the actual solution ([demo](http://ideone.com/bb7AUB)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
  std::bitset<16> b { "0100000101000010" }; // "AB"
  std::bitset<16> m { "0000000011111111" }; // 0xff
  for ( int i = 0; i < 2; ++i )
  {
    std::cout << char( ( b & m ).to_ullong() ); // will display "BA"
    b >>= 8;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT - one day later**

A possible solution ([demo](http://ideone.com/ycEXhk)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>

template < std::size_t N >
std::string to_text( std::bitset< N > b )
{
  return b.any()
    ? to_text( b >>= 8 ) + char( b.to_ullong() & 0xff )
    : "";
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << to_text( std::bitset<16> { "0100000101000010" } );
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: g++ can't compile it.

Comment: @JianxinLi Ideone compiler is based on GCC (see the demo link above). What's the actual error?

Answer (score 1):

Use [std::bitset::to_string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/to_string/), like this:

```
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <string>         // std::string
#include <bitset>         // std::bitset

void bitsetToChar(std::bitset<64> mybits) {
    std::bitset<8> bit;
    for(int i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
    {
        bit[i % 8] = mybits[i];
        if((i - 7) % 8 == 0)
        {
            std::string mystring = bit.to_string<char,std::string::traits_type,std::string::allocator_type>();
            std::cout << "mystring: " << mystring << '\n';
        }
    }
}

int main ()
{
  std::bitset<64> mybits;
  mybits.set();
  bitsetToChar(mybits);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ g++ -Wall main.cpp 
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out 
mystring: 11111111
mystring: 11111111
mystring: 11111111
mystring: 11111111
mystring: 11111111
mystring: 11111111
mystring: 11111111
mystring: 11111111
```

I think this is what you want to do. Be careful not to go out of bounds when accessing the bitset.

---

If this is not enough, please take a look at [How to convert string of binary values back to char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30584463/how-to-convert-string-of-binary-values-back-to-char)?

Comment: In fact, it's not my plan. If  bit = 01000001, I want convert it to `A` and so on.

Comment: I have an idea that first covert 8 bits to long and then conver long to char.I'm not sure.

Comment: I believe the desired behavior is that, if the bitset is `std::bitset<64>(0x61'31'62'32'63'33'64'34)`, then a single string results which is `a1b2c3d4`. The `to_string` method does not do this.

Comment: @gsamaras You also have some weird `$` symbol at the end of `std::string mystring` line.

Comment: Why are you fixing minor mistakes in your answer when the update to the question clarifies that the answer doesn’t even apply to what’s being asked?

Comment: Because I hadn't see them Daniel H. Another answer is posted, good thing that it will be accepted. In any case, a wrong answer is not nice.